# Operator associavity problem with pre and post increment :(

Tags: c, gcc, operator-keyword, associativity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

```
#include< stdio.h >

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int x = ++i * ++i * ++i;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d\n\n",i);

    return 0;
}
```

Im getting output of 1!! and 4 in gcc. I use ubuntu linux

Comment: Well, I'm getting "warning: operation on 'i' may be undefined" when I compile with `gcc -Wall`.  You should use -Wall and pay attention to the warnings.

Comment: There's a C++-faq question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is undefined since `i` is modified more than once between sequence points:

```
int x = ++i * ++i * ++i;
```

See the [FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html) (I urge you to read the entire [section 3](http://c-faq.com/expr/index.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Undefined Behaviour this is:

```
int x = ++i * ++i * ++i;
```

Don't do it!!!!